# How do i insert my parsed Json object in sqlite database OnClick getJson?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

```
//**MainActivity**
-----------------------------------------------------------------
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String json_string;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public TextView textView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void getJson(View view){

        new MainActivity.BackgroundTask(this).execute();

    }

    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;
        Context context;


        public BackgroundTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute(){

            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading.....Please Wait");
            progressDialog.show();

            json_url="http://demo5629995.mockable.io/Employee1";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try{
                URL url=new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_STRING=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void values){
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        public void onPostExecute(String result){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjson);
            textView.setText(result);
            json_string=result;

        }
    }

    public void parseJson(View view){


        if(json_string==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"get Json",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,JsonDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("json_data",json_string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

// **JsonDisplayActivity**
    _______________________________________________________________

```
public class JsonDisplayActivity extends Activity {
    String json_string;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    EmployeeAdapter employeeAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaylistview);

        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


        json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("emp");
            int count=0;
            String name,email,url;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){

                JSONObject jo=jsonArray.optJSONObject(count);
                name=jo.getString("Name");
                email=jo.getString("Email");
                url=jo.getString("Url");

                employee emp=new employee(name,email,url);
               // employeeAdapter.add(emp);
                empList.add(emp);
                count++;



            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        employeeAdapter=new EmployeeAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_row,empList);
        listView.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);
    }
}
```

//  **EmployeeAdapter**
    _____________________________________________________________________

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list;
    public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<employee> employeeList) {
        super(context, resource);
        list=employeeList;
    }

    public void add(employee object){
        super.add(object);
       list.add(object);
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row=convertView;
        EmployeeHolder employeeholder;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row,parent,false);
            employeeholder=new EmployeeHolder();
            employeeholder.tv_name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            employeeholder.tv_email= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvemail);
            employeeholder.tv_url= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvUrl);

            row.setTag(employeeholder);
        }
        else {
            employeeholder=(EmployeeHolder)row.getTag();
        }
      //  employee emp= (employee) this.getItem(position);
        employee emp= (employee) list.get(position);
        employeeholder.tv_name.setText(emp.getName());
        employeeholder.tv_email.setText(emp.getEmail());
        employeeholder.tv_url.setText(emp.getUrl());

        return row;
    }

    static class EmployeeHolder{
        TextView tv_name,tv_email,tv_url;
    }
}
```

//  **employee**
    __________________________________________________________

```
public class employee {
    String name;
    String email;
    String url;

    public employee(String name, String email,String url){
        this.setName(name);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setUrl(url);


    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try from convert the Json to Pojo. Then insert it to sqlite using orm , or using simple query by passing the pojo to the database handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DETAILS = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(/*YOUR JSON DATA*/);

        DETAILS.clear();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        int i = 0;
        //Users.clear();
        for(i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            hashmap.put("NAME", c.getString("NAME"));
            hashmap.put("EMAIL", c.getString("EMAIL"));
            hashmap.put("URL", c.getString("URL"));
            DETAILS.add(hashmap);
        }
        if (i >= data.length())
        {
         DatabaseHelper DH = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            DH.addIntoUsers(DETAILS);
            DH.close();
            Log.d("USERS:", ""+DETAILS);

        }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and in your DatabaseHelper class you should declare the function

```
public void addIntoCases(ArrayList<?> arraylist)
{   
    SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqlitedatabase.delete("EMPLOYEE_TBL", null, null);

    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++){
        contentvalues.put("NAME", (String)((HashMap<?, ?>)arraylist.get(i)).get("NAME")); 
        contentvalues.put("EMAIL", (String)((HashMap)arraylist.get(i)).get("EMAIL"));
        contentvalues.put("URL", (String)((HashMap<?, ?>)arraylist.get(i)).get("URL"));

         sqlitedatabase.insert("EMPLOYEE_TBL", null, contentvalues);
    }
    return;
}
```

your table should be like:

```
sqlitedatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_TBL(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NAME TEXT,EMAIL TEXT,URL TEXT)");
```